# How to hide dark mode icon on the image preview

Tags: templates, themes, customization, blogger

The Dark mode icon is displayed in front of the image preview. How to hide it?
Sample Test Page: https://www.aluth.com/2021/05/apple-airtag-how-it-works-features-and.html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zszN6.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the icon appears in front of the preview because it has `z-index: 999;`.

set the `z-index` of the preview box and make it greater than 999

```css
.CSS_LIGHTBOX {
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

you can read more about [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) property

Comment: I changed it to,

z-index: 0;

Now ok. Thanks Dude !